# Reading data from text file and store it in html table using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html-table

I have a text file that contains data that looks like being formatted in a table. But they are just ordered lines of text made to resemble a table. I am trying to read the text file, get data and store in HTML table.

The text file looks like:

```
Sl.No., Project Name, ChangeDate, Changed By
01, 01, 02, 03
02, 04, 05, 06
03, 07, 08, 09
04, 10, 11, 12
05, 13, 14, 15
06, 16, 17, 18
07, 19, 20, 21
08, 22, 23, 24
09, 25, 26, 27
010, 28, 29, 30
011, 31, 32, 33
012, 34, 35, 36
013, 37, 38, 39
014, 40, 41, 42
015, 43, 44, 45
016, 46, 47, 48
017, 49, 50, 51
018, 52, 53, 54
019, 55, 56, 57
020, 58, 59, 60
```

I used this code to create the html table, looks like:

```
<html>
<script>
function makeTable()
{
    var row_num = 20;
    var cell_num = 4;

    var tab = document.createElement('table');
    tab.setAttribute('id','newtable');

    var tbo = document.createElement('tbody');
    tbo.setAttribute('id','tabody');

    var cont;
    for(var c = 0 ; c < row_num ; c++)
    {
        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        for(var k = 0 ; k < cell_num ; k++)
        {
            var cell = document.createElement('td');
            if (k > 0)
            {
                cont = document.createElement("input");
                cont.setAttribute('type','text');
            }
            else
            {
                cont = document.createTextNode("0" + (c+1));
            }
            cell.appendChild(cont);
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }
        tbo.appendChild(row);
    }
    tab.appendChild(tbo);
    document.body.appendChild(tab);
    tab.setAttribute("align", "top-left");
}
window.onload = function()
{
    makeTable();
};

function GetCellValues()
{
    var str = '';
    var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var table=document.getElementById("project");
    for (var i=0;i<table.rows[0].cells.length;i++)
    {
        if (i > 2 )
        {
            str = str + table.rows[0].cells[3].innerHTML.replace(", ");
        }
        else
        {
            str = str + (table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML) + ', ' ;
        }
    }
    for (var c = 1 ; c < rows.length ; c++)
    {
        str += '\n' + "0" + c + ', ';
        var row = rows[c];
        var inputs = row.getElementsByTagName('input');                
        for (var k = 0 ; k < inputs.length ; k++)
        if (k > 1)
        {
            str += inputs[k].value.replace(", ");
        }
        else 
        {
            str += inputs[k].value + ', ';
        }
    }   
    document.getElementById('hide').value = str;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action = "project.php" method = "POST">
<h1><u>PROJECT</u> :</h1>
<input type="hidden" id="hide" name="hide" value="">
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick = "GetCellValues()" />
<table id = "project" border = "1" width ="60%" class = "newtable" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<th align="center" width ="200px" id = "Sl.No." >Sl.No.</th>
<th align="center" width ="200px" id = "Project Name" >Project Name</th>
<th align="center" width ="200px" id = "ChangeDate" >ChangeDate</th>
<th align="center" width ="200px" id = "Changed By" >Changed By</th>
</tr>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I want to store this text file in this table.

I used this code to retrieve the data from table and store it in txt file:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("data.txt", "w");
$hide =$_REQUEST['hide'];
fwrite($handle,$hide);
echo $hide;
?>
```

I used this code to convert txt file into array:

```
<?php
    $text = file_get_contents("data.csv");
    $fixed_text = str_replace("\n", "<br>", $text);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r ( explode( ',', $fixed_text ) );
    echo '</pre>';
    //echo ( explode( ',', $fixed_text ) );
    //echo $fixed_text;         
?>
```

Now I want to store this text file data into table.
How can I store this text file data into table?

Comment: using text format is silly....create arrays and convert to json

Comment: store it in json, send it in json, loop arrays in javascript to poplulate table. Instead of wrap in `<pre>` use `echo json_encode( array)`

Comment: Use json, you can't go wrong.

Comment: google `parse json html`

Comment: Please kindly give me some code regarding this.....@charlietfl